# My wildcard sub-domains are not working properly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, virtualhost, wildcard-subdomain

Hie all,

I'm trying to make a dynamic sub domains for my users like **username.host.com** instead of **www.host.com/user.php?user=username**

For that i created a A RECORD in my hosting like 
**`*.mosto.in   208.91.199.44   Active`**

In my .htaccess file i've added the following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}                 ^www\.[^.]+\.mosto\.in$
RewriteRule   ^(.+)                        %{HTTP_HOST}$1          [C]
RewriteRule   ^www\.([^.]+)\.mosto\.in(.*) /home/$1$2
```

The above code i found on Apache official website http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html#content

But when i trying to open **dev.mosto.in** is not opening.

Any clues or ideas ? Where i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: So `dev.mosto.in` should show content of `http://dev.mosto.in/user.php?dev` ?

Comment: **`dev.mosto.in`** should show **`http://www.mosto.in/user.php?user=dev`**

Comment: but aren't `dev.mosto.in` and `www.mosto.in` pointing to same host/ip?

Comment: Yes those are pointing to same IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.mosto.in/user.php?user=%1 [L,QSA,R]
```

Comment: I believe `dev.mosto.in` and `www.mosto.in` both point to same DOCUMENT_ROOT is it true? And did you try this URL: `http://dev.mosto.in` for testing?

Comment: Yes the both points to *`public_html`* and if i open http://dev.mosto.in is says **`Firefox can't find the server at dev.mosto.in.`**

Comment: If you're getting that error then it means your wildcard domain is not setup properly.

Comment: Ohh let me check with my Hosting people and post back to you, thanks for helping me dude.

Comment: Even `dig dev.mosto.in` or `nslookup dev.mosto.in` are failing so I guess you need to work with your hosting co regarding this.

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirecting wildcard subdomains to store.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.mosto.in
RewriteRule (.*)  store.php?store=%1
```

Fixed my problem.